# Excel: Search for all zip files inside a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro ([Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/16598706)) that looks inside a folder for zip files, but the problem is that the last zip file has an empty string as a name. How can I avoid that error.

The code for the macro:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    ' Define variables
    Dim file As String, folder As String

    ' Define working directory
    folder = "C:\Users\cportocarrero\Desktop\Curvas\"

    ' Define type of file to search for
    file = Dir(folder & "*.zip")

    ' Loop through all the files
    Do While Len(file) > 0
        Debug.Print file
        file = Dir
        MsgBox file
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are Debug.Printing one value of `file` but then you are changing the the `file` variable before sending to MsgBox. KekuSemau's answer shows how your loop should be structured. Your `While` test doesn't need to change as `Len(file) > 0` will have same effect as `file <> ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the loop like this:
- first call to `dir` before the loop, then
- the while loop
- call to `dir` should be the last command inside the loop

```
file = Dir(folder & "*.zip")
Do While file <> ""
    Debug.Print file
    MsgBox file
    file = Dir
Loop
```

When `dir` returns an empty string, this means that there are no more matches.

Comment: +1 I'm being picky here, but the call to `Dir` *should* be the last command inside the loop, but doesn't *have* to be. It just needs to be after all usage of the `file` variable.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. +1 for being picky, I have edited that.